# Задача из Практикума Яндекс по JS

Tags: javascript

Есть задача по JS
Напишите функцию, которая будет возвращать коллекцию DOM-узлов всех цен на основании переданного селектора в виде Array (не `NodeList`).

```
function getDomNodesBySelector(selector) {
  // Ваш код   
} 
console.log(getDomNodesBySelector('.price-value'));
```

Нужно использовать spread или `Array.from`.
Добавлял `return [...selector]` - система не принимает ответ.
Пробовал return `Array.from(selector)` - аналогично.

Что не так?

Comment: selector это же строка (для выборки узлов), а вам нужны DOM узлы, то есть соответствующие Node'ы из DOM.

Comment: Дело в том, что  nodeList  это другой тип, ну это не массив, это именно тип  nodeList,   он не имеет некоторых методов, например  map  ибо это есть только у массива.

Comment: const arr = [...nodeL]     сначала получаем саму ноду const nodeL = document.querySelectorAll('a');

Answer (score 0):

Для получения списка узлов по селектору можно воспользоваться методом [`.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Так как результатом является `NodeList` из него нужно сделать `Array`, например с помощью метода [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), в итоге код может быть таким:

```
return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))
```